# How To Calculate values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, aggregate

I have  mysql table like this, I want to ask, how do I get the value obtained no_id 1 of total / all_total?

I want to display on the diagram, so I want to take the value 78/150 for name Geori and 45/150 for Rosy with one query. please help me sir.

Select * from user;

No_id    Name    Total

1           Geori    78

2            Rosy    45

Select * from calculate;

All_Total   Parameter 1 Parameter 2

150             123            27

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Comment: I want to display on the diagram, so I want to take the value 78/150 for name Geori and 45/150 for Rosy with one query. please help me sir. thank you

Comment: Is there only one record in `calculate`?And how to handle cases when there is more than one record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get no_id 1's total / all_total

```
select a.name, a.total / b.all_total
from user a
join calculate b;
```

Comment: what if I want to know the total amount of no_id 1 and 2? thanks

Comment: @user3717096, you mean how to get 78 + 45 in mysql?

Comment: I want to display on the diagram, so I want to take the value 78/150 for name Geori and 45/150 for Rosy with one query. please help me sir. thank you

Comment: I want to display on the diagram, so I want to take the value 78/150 for name Geori and 45/150 for Rosy with one query. please help me sir. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to join the table using a column you need a cross join. 
*CROSS JOIN returns the Cartesian product of rows from tables in the join. In other words, it will produce rows which combine each row from the first table with each row from the second table. see: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join*

```
select u.name, u.total / c.all_total
from user u
cross join calculate c;
```

Comment: The important is the cross nature of the join, if you have multiple rows in calculate, it will do all the permutations.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your answer?

Comment: CROSS JOIN returns the Cartesian product of rows from tables in the join. In other words, it will produce rows which combine each row from the first table with each row from the second table. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join